# Refresh page when file on server change

Tags: php, apache, refresh

In my wwwroot I placed file 123.txt. My simple service puts string to this file. Also, in index.php I use the content of 123.txt as a variable. How can I force browser to refresh the page when 123.txt file is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the value in javascript at page load, then poll the file every X seconds to see if it's changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let originalValue = "<?php echo file_get_contents('123.txt'); ?>";
function checkFileForChanges() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               if (xmlhttp.responseText != originalValue) {
                   window.location.reload();
               }
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              //alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
              // alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "123.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

let interval = setInterval(()=> {
checkFileForChanges();
}, (30*1000)) // every 30 seconds
</script>
```